# Do the Jews believe that prophet L. Ron Hubbard is their prophet?

Tags: navi-prophets, nevua-prophecy

Shalom friends do the Jews believe that prophet L. Ron Hubbard is their prophet do the Jews follow his teachings also what do the Jews think of prophet L. Ron Hubbard. Thank you Shalom.

Answer (score 4):

No, Judaism doesn't believe Mr. Hubbard is a prophet. ([Source.](/q/17727)) Nor does it follow his teachings except such as happen to coincide with Judaism: i.e., it doesn't follow his teachings because they're his teachings. (My only source is a lifetime to date of learning about Judaism and never hearing his name mentioned in that context.) (Nonetheless, there are doubtless some [Jews](/a/52892/170) who do so believe and follow.)